# Swiper Angular bug on carousel

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I want to do a carousel with gestures in my angular application, but photos should be on a specific box.
In that way, I want to hide the 2 photos on the left side of the box as you can see: [bug on Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUR3z.png)

Here is my code:

```
config: SwiperOptions = {
    pagination: { el: '.swiper-pagination', clickable: true },
    allowTouchMove: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    breakpoints: {
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 3
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    },
    centeredSlides: true,

  };
```

In HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="photosOpen" class="carousel">
        <div class="numberPhotos" *ngIf="!preference.english" [ngClass]="{'numberPhotosBig':preference.fontBig=='big'}">
            {{item.photos.length}} φωτογραφίες</div>

        <div class="numberPhotos" *ngIf="preference.english" [ngClass]="{'numberPhotosBig':preference.fontBig=='big'}">
            {{item.photos.length}} photos</div>

        <swiper [config]="config" class="swiper-container">

            <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="centerPhotos" [ngClass]="{'cont':preference.fontBig=='big'}">

                <div class="swiper-slide column twoPhotos" *ngFor="let slide of item.photos ">
                    <img class="photos" src="{{slide}}" />
                    <div>{{slide}}</div>
                </div>

            </div>


            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

            <!-- Add Arrows -->
            <div class="swiper-button-next">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev">
            </div>

        </swiper>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: `.swiper-container {overflow:hidden}` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it didn't worked in this class but it worked in a custom one